# Is that a good idea to start a React project with an UI framework?

Tags: css, user-interface, reactjs, material-ui

I'm starting a new website from scratch and I was wondering if React UI Framework are worth the try for building a website, or it's better to create my own components, grid etc...
I really like projects such as ElementalUI's Take on bootstrap3, MaterialUI forms components, Grommet, but they don't mix well together, some are using SASS, other LESS...

During previous projects, I've used some UI frameworks, but when I needed to do something that was not thinked by the creator of the framework, it was less complicated to create it myself than finding a workaround, and often more elegant.

I'm thinking that building my own React components using SASS and CSS3 could be the best solution.

Thanks!

Comment: This will probably be closed as opinion-based, but I'd say yes - if you're looking to prototype quickly, using pre-packaged components like Material UI can be a good jumping off point. That said, you will begin to encounter limitations when your needs deepen, however often times a good component library can offer some decent inspiration for when you finally do need to create your own

Comment: This is exactly my mindset right now,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent and complicated to answer question at the same time.

I've been involved in few React projects, with different teams, and most of time, we were composing our components sets with customs style and when we needed a specific thing, the way to go was npm, for instance a custom range date picker.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure; I wrote a great deal of ElementalUI.

I recommend researching each of the available UI frameworks and deciding whether they have the components and functionality required for your project. I also recommend looking into the components themselves to see how and why the authors solved a problem the way they did - that's probably the most valuable thing.

Elemental, and most other frameworks, are really helpful for applications where the UI must be consistent throughout. My own experience has been that for websites you're better off building your own components.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually, I think that one who's comfortable with CSS3 should create his/her own components from scratch.